# tikz-qtree and linguex

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree, qtree

I am using `tikz-qtree` and I don't seem to able to use it properly with `linguex`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\ex. 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.DP
            [.D the ]
            [.{\itshape a}P
                    [.{} 
                        [.{}
                            [.$\sqrt{\textsc{boring}}$ boring ]
                            [.{\itshape a} ]
                        ]
                        [.$\phi$ ]
                    ]
            [.NP \edge[roof]; {writer} ] 
            ]
        ] 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The `linguex` numbering aligns with the leaves, but I would like to have it align with the root node.

[image]

I know I should use `forest`, but I was curious about any possible solution for this with `tikz-qtree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[baseline]` to the tikzpicture environment. I have also successfully tested it with `expex`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\ex. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree [.DP
            [.D the ]
            [.{\itshape a}P
                    [.{} 
                        [.{}
                            [.$\sqrt{\textsc{boring}}$ boring ]
                            [.{\itshape a} ]
                        ]
                        [.$\phi$ ]
                    ]
            [.NP \edge[roof]; {writer} ] 
            ]
        ] 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```